# access file from hive streaming script in c# (HDInsight)

Tags: c#, hadoop, streaming, cloud, hive

I'm using a Hive streaming job to process some data in C# on HDInsight. In order to process the data, the script has to read an xml file stored as a blob on Azure like so:

```
        OperationContext oc = new OperationContext();
        CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(asvAccount, asvKey), true);
        CloudBlobClient client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = client.GetContainerReference("myContainer");
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("file/f.xml");
        MemoryStream stream;
        using (stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            blob.DownloadToStream(stream);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string reader = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
            elem = XElement.Parse(reader);
            return elem;
        }
```

The code works on my local machine: it reads the file from the storage account and returns elem correctly, but when I try to run it on the cluster, it has a problem finding Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll even though I add it via fs.put() to /Hive/Resources/ and then do "add file" in the hive portal.

If I try accessing the file like this:

```
XElement.Load("hdinsighttesting.blob.core.windows.net/repexdeema/pr/productGuidMapping.xml");
```

or

```
XElement.Load("asv://myContainer@myCluster.blob.core.windows.net/file/f.xml"); then I get the following error: 

Could not find a part of the path 'c:\hdfs\mapred\local\taskTracker\admin\jobcache\job_201307200714_0079\attempt_201307200714_0079_m_000000_0\work\storageAccount.blob.core.windows.net\myContainer\pr\productGuidMapping.xml
```

I don't understand why it's insisting on looking in that directory instead of just going directly to the blob storage.  I tried going to that directory but it doesn't exist.

I also thought of using LocalResource but that's not possible in my case because Hive is refusing to find the dll files that I'm uploading into the hdfs.

Thanks

Comment: were u able to resolve

Answer (score 0):

"add file" should be sufficient. It will copy dll into working folder and should be available to your script. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll has dependencies of its own. I believe on OData.dll and edm.dll. Make sure you add file all of its dependencies otherwise it will fail to load.